how do I map <F7> to :argument with the file buffer number as input
I have several files opened with :argadd command. To traverse the files I use F2 and F3 which is mapped to :prev and :next.
When a number like 15 and F7 is pressed then it should do
:argument 15

which will go to file at buffer 15.
How do I map F7 to :argument<CR>
I have tried the following and it did not work:
map <F7> :<C-U>argument v:count<CR>

